# BeautifulSoup Cannot Find Tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape [this page](http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/index.php?pid=99556)  and all of the other pages like it. I have been using BeautifulSoup (also have tried lxml but there have been installation issues). I am using the following code:

```
value = "http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/index.php?pid=99556"
desiredTag = "span"
r = urllib2.urlopen(value)
data = BeautifulSoup(r.read(), 'html5lib') 
displayText = data.find_all(desiredTag)
print displayText
displayText = " ".join(str(displayText))
displayText = BeautifulSoup(displayText, 'html5lib')
```

For some reason this isn't pull back the `<span class="displaytext">` and also I have tried `desiredTag` as `p`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are definitely experiencing the differences [between different parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers) used by `BeautifulSoup`. `html.parser` and `lxml` worked for me:

```
data = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(value), 'html.parser')
```

Proof:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> url = "http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/index.php?pid=99556"
>>> 
>>> data = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url), 'html.parser')
>>> data.find("span", class_="displaytext").text
u'PARTICIPANTS:Former Speaker of the House Newt Gingrich (GA);
...
```

Comment: This is a great and clearly thorough answer. I have seen this when looking around but I am getting an "HTMLParser.HTMLParseError: Malformed start tag, at line 1183 column 15" With exactly this code on that site. Is it possible that I have something incorrect installed?

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot okay, quick check: which Python version are you using? Thanks.

Comment: 2.7.2 from Active Python. It's an anaconda install

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot if this is not a big deal, could you try upgrading to 2.7.6 at least (2.7.9 would be better)?

Comment: For future reference I am pretty sure the python upgrade was important